# Open webpage on iPad from Mac

Tags: ipad

Is there an app out there that I can have on my mac that does the following:

Basically if I am on a website on my macbook, I want to be able to click a button on the browser and the same page to pop open wirelessly on my ipad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Handoff](http://www.handoffapp.com/).

Comment: I've been using Handoff for at least a year. I feel like the push notification used to be faster — almost instantaneous — but now there's a little bit of a delay between when I send the page and the push notification comes through. If I'm in the Handoff app on my iPad, though, I get it right away.

Answer (score 2):

Not natively, but as others have pointed out, some third party software does that.

In iOS 5, you'd be able to save it to a bookmark (or a "reading list") that will be synced automatically to your iPad through iCloud. That's the closest one I can think of. Just make a bookmark folder of "Open on iPad", and put it on your bookmarks bar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of options thus far.

- Safari's native Reading List
- [Handoff](http://www.handoffapp.com/)
- [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/)
- [Ansible](http://www.ansibleapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/), and the browser add-ons that go with it. I use [Send2Prowl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/send2prowl/) for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

[Ansible](http://www.ansibleapp.com/) is a good option.